# YII CDBCriteria filter columns

Tags: mysql, yii

I fairly new to YII and still trying to understand it all.  However from what I can tell when you do something like

```
    yourModel->findAll(criteria)
```

Is like "Select * from"?  or is it more like "Select yourModel->Attributes from"?  In either case I was wondering in CDbCriteria is there a way to remove columns from the select.  My case I have a user table that contains password I would like to prevent this from being added in the query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ofcourse you can select specific columns, just use the [`select` property of CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail):

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select='column1, column2';// or you can use array array('column1','column2')
$manymodels=$yourmodel->findAll($criteria);
```

So it is more like : "Select criteria->select from yourmodelclass' dbtable".

Note that [`findAll()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) will return you an array of models.

Comment: Awesome thanks I think this is what I was looking for.  I will give it a shot when I get home.

Comment: you are welcome, always glad to help, read the documentation links for more info.